# EDatabaseError "zqryLista: Field 'Número' not found" quando o alias contém "/"

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, delphi-7

Existe um campo na SQL do meu form com o Alias "Número/Minuta", e quando a SQL é executada pela segunda vez a mensagem *Field 'Número' not found* é disparada. Eu consigo resolver isso dando um Close e depois Open na query, porém não posso fazer isso, pois altera o funcionamento da tela.

O que percebi foi que na mensagem só aparece 'Número' como campo not found e não 'Número/Minuta'. Se eu retirar "/" do alias e deixar "Número Minuta", por exemplo, funciona normalmente. Gostaria de saber qual a relação da "/" no nome com este erro.

Obs: o erro não é só da barra, mas aparentemente pra qualquer símbolo, pois se eu colocar "Número@Minuta" no alias, o erro também é disparado.

O trecho onde ocorre o erro:

```
with zqryLista do
begin
   if zqryLista.Active then
   begin
      zqryLista.Refresh;
   end
   else
      zqryLista.Open;
end;
```

Comment: Sugiro não usar símbolos no alias. Use a propriedade DisplayText do Field: zqryLista.FieldByName('NUMERO').DisplayText := 'Número/Minuta';

Comment: É uma query dinâmica construída em tempo de execução, o alias é usado pra atribuir os nomes das colunas de um grid, e a sql pode mudar a cada execução, por isso tem que ser feito com o alias

Comment: Alisson, acho que dificilmente você vais deixar de ter problemas com este tipo de nome de campo. Mesmo com a query criada dinamicamente, é possível encontrar uma estratégia melhor para nomear os campos. Para exibir um texto diferente na coluna do grid, DisplayText do objeto de campo resolve. Também é possível ajustar o título de exibição nos objetos de coluna do grid. Como você diz que na 1ª vez funciona, uma opção é criar o objeto de query também dinamicamente, assim estará sempre na primeira vez.

Answer (score 0):

Não é recomendado usar símbolos nem acentos em alias em campos, como já disseram. E sobre aceitar símbolos ou não geralmente vai mais sobre sintaxe do SGDB.

Talvez o que seja aceite é entre aspas "Número/Minuta" no SQL(depende do SGDB) em querys.

Porém vc deve ter vinculado algum field na sua ClientDataset/dataset, que ficaria ruim, pois teria que ter o mesmo nome, não é uma boa pratica.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.